# cannot set tree nodes in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, treenode

I try to use tree node using primefaces but I'm not able to set the nodes using my controller

I wrote this code

```
                <p:tree value="#{myModel.root}" var="node"
                    selectionMode="checkbox"
                    selection="#{myModel.selectedNodes}"
                    style="width: 100%">
                    <p:treeNode>
                        <h:outputText value="#{node.description}" />
                    </p:treeNode>
                </p:tree>
```

here is the managed bean

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped    
public class TreeBean implements Serializable {  

private TreeNode root;  

private TreeNode selectedNode;  

public TreeBean() {  
    root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);  
    TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0", root);  
    TreeNode node1 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1", root);  
    TreeNode node2 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 2", root);  

    TreeNode node00 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0", node0);  
    TreeNode node01 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1", node0);  

    TreeNode node10 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0", node1);  
    TreeNode node11 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.1", node1);  

    TreeNode node000 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.0", node00);  
    TreeNode node001 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.1", node00);  
    TreeNode node010 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1.0", node01);  

    TreeNode node100 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0.0", node10);  
}  

public TreeNode getRoot() {  
    return root;  
}  

public TreeNode getSelectedNode() { 
            selectedNodes=new TreeNode[allNodes.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < allNodes.size(); i++) {
        selectedNodes[i]=allNodes.get(i);
        if (i==0||i==100) {
            selectedNodes[i].setSelected(true);
        }else {
            selectedNodes[i].setSelected(false);
        }
    }
    return selectedNode;  
}  

public void setSelectedNode(TreeNode selectedNode) {  
    this.selectedNode = selectedNode;  
}  
}
```

when I click on a button in the tree page it works but I have to set the information before open it

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the datatype of selectedNode from a single object of type TreeNode to an array container of TreeNode(s).

change

```
private TreeNode selectedNode;
```

to

```
private TreeNode[] selectedNodes;
```

because you set selectionMode="checkbox" where multiple rows can be selected, and these need to be stored in an array.